# How to make specific line cut-off points without using <br/> breaks because it fails responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Our marketing is very explicit on how things look. I got screenshot on how lines of specific section must look like.

[image]

At the moment code looks like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="call-to-action">
    <p>Thank you for using the Saga @ViewData["LegalReference"] fee calculator. All details are checked by<br />our trained solicitors at point of instruct. To instruct us or for a written quotation<br />please click on the Buy Now button or call one of our UK based advisers on <br/><span><strong>@ViewData["ContactNumber"]</strong> quoting <strong>@ViewData["ProductReference"]</strong></span></p>
    <p>Lines are open 8am &ndash; 8pm Monday to Friday, 9am &ndash; 5pm Saturday and 10am &ndash; 2pm Sunday. </p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.call-to-action p 
{
    margin:0em -1em 0em -1em;
}
.call-to-action p + p 
{
    margin: 0em 7.5em 0em 6.5em;
}
```

Reason for using breaks (`<br/>`) is that `@ViewData["LegalReference"]` can be word 'conveyancing' which is a long word that makes words jump down, and lines have to jump down on specific words (after 'by','quotation','on')

**Problem: Since web site is responsive on mobile with `<br/>` it starts to look like this**

[image]

So if instead of `<br/>` i tried to use margins.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="call-to-action">
    <p>Thank you for using the Saga @ViewData["LegalReference"] fee calculator. All details are checked by our trained solicitors at point of instruct. To instruct us or for a written quotation please click on the Buy Now button or call one of our UK based advisers on <span><strong>@ViewData["ContactNumber"]</strong> quoting <strong>@ViewData["ProductReference"]</strong></span></p>
    <p>Lines are open 8am &ndash; 8pm Monday to Friday, 9am &ndash; 5pm Saturday and 10am &ndash; 2pm Sunday. </p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.call-to-action p 
{
    margin:0em 1.4em 0em 0em;
}
.call-to-action p + p 
{
    margin: 0em 7.5em 0em 6.5em;
}
```

I get this:

[image]

**How could I make lines to break on specific words ('by','quotation','on') in such a way that when in responsive it would not break on them an would fill full length?**

Comment: Have you tried CSS3 { word-break: break-all; }?

Comment: can you use media queries?

Comment: @SunilKumar not sure how breaking in the middle of the word would help me. Could you explain in more detail please.

Comment: @web-tiki Yes I can. That's how responsiveness is being controlled ATM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a mediaquery, for smaller resolutions, in which you hide the `<br />`, e.g.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   br { display: none }
}
```

this will ensure a natural line-break dependant on the element width only

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogqzVr

Comment: Wow i didn't know I could hide `<br/>` - very clever indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to change the value of `white-space` of the paragraph to `pre-line` in desktop mode, and re-set it back to `normal` in small screens:

```css
p {
  white-space: pre-line;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  p { white-space: normal; }
}
```

```html
<p>Thank you for using the Saga LegalReference fee calculator. All details are checked by
  our trained solicitors at point of instruct. To instruct us or for a written quotation
  please click on the Buy Now button or call one of our UK based advisers on
  <span><strong>ContactNumber</strong> quoting <strong>ProductReference</strong></span></p>
```

---

You could also hide the `<br />` elements by adding `display: none;` to them in specific screen sizes.

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  br { display: none; }
}
```

```html
<p>Thank you for using the Saga LegalReference fee calculator. All details are checked by <br /> our trained solicitors at point of instruct. To instruct us or for a written quotation <br /> please click on the Buy Now button or call one of our UK based advisers on <br /> <span><strong>ContactNumber</strong> quoting <strong>ProductReference</strong></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

use nonbreakingspace `&nbsp;` for text you dont want to break like phone no.